# Missing CC button in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, mozilla, subtitle, webvtt

I am working with subtitles (WebVtt) in HTML5.
A button to toggle subtitles on/off should appear on the video player.
But in firefox this does not happen.
Working example here, a simple test using webvtt subtitles:
http://www.erher.no/TEMP/HTML5/subtitle/webvtt.html

problem With Firefox is that no CC button appears?

I'm able to force subtitle to display by setting the "default" parameter in the track tag, so it is working, but where is the CC button?

Mozilla and WebVtt:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Video_Text_Tracks_Format

anyone?

Comment: Do you have any code for this problem so we can see if there's some code missing or that needs amending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox simply hasn't implemented a native control for it yet. You can see [the feature request in their bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=887934).

If you want a control, you'll have to implement it yourself with JavaScript.